# Using configuration file for OpenSSL's EVP API

Tags: go, openssl, openssl-engine

### Background

When using OpenSSL via the command-line, I am able to change the default engine by setting my `openssl.cnf` (see **Sample code** below). I now want to change the default engine while using the EVP API, ideally by changing a config file.

The larger context is that I am using a [Go wrapper around EVP](https://github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl), which supports neither setting the engine globally nor setting the engine for signing/verifying (the only operations I care about). I am investigating options (e.g. using cgo to [set the engine globally](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/ENGINE_set_default.html) or forking the library) involving code changes, but it would be ideal if I could avoid them.

### Issue

EVP does not seem to read the config file and I can't find/understand documentation online on whether this is possible or not. Is the configuration file automatically loaded (and I'm just doing it wrong?) or do I need to do something like call [OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CONFIG](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/OPENSSL_INIT_set_config_appname.html)?

### Sample code

```
openssl_conf = openssl_def

[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section

[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
dynamic_path = /usr/local/Cellar/engine_pkcs11/0.1.8/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so
MODULE_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/opensc/0.19.0/lib/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so
PIN = "123456"
init = 0
```

```
$ openssl engine
(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
(pkcs11) pkcs11 engine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using OpenSSL 1.1.0 or later then try inserting the following at the beginning of your program (before you do any other OpenSSL call):

```
    OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CONFIG, NULL);
```

Comment: Sadly, I was not able to find a way to automatically load a configuration file and the [README.ENGINE](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/README.ENGINE) makes no mention of being able to do so.

Comment: Looks like the only two options are calling `OPENSSL_init_crypto()` as Matt suggested, or building the engine piece-by-piece à la the example given in [README.ENGINE](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/README.ENGINE) using `ENGINE_by_id("dynamic")`